# unity restrict moving object on a plane

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to restrict a moving object on a plane( the plane may be or may not be a square) here is the prototype:

[image]

I attached a mesh collider to the plane and hope to use that to restrict the movement of the sphere the sphere will move randomly, the idea is that when the ball moved to the edge the velocity will be reflected so it will not fall off the plane with this:

```
public class BallScript : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(0.1f,0,0.1f);

    }

    private void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = -GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity;
    }
}
```

but the ball kept fall at the edge,

I can't make edge colliders cause the shape of the plane will not be decided until runtime.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: When you say edge collider, do you mean [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-EdgeCollider2D.html)?

Comment: No, I have noticed there is an exact 2d edge collider but not 3d, what I mean is build sort of "wall" around at the plane edge to keep the ball inside using colliders

Comment: Hmmm did you try doing a [RayCast](https://www.google.com.ph/search?q=hit+unity&oq=hit+unity&aqs=chrome..69i57.8867j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)?

Comment: @TheGinxx009 do you mean a raycast shoot from the ball and detect the edge face of the plane?

Comment: You could do it actually using `SqrMagnitude` and `RayCast`

Comment: @TheGinxx009 let me know if I understand the idea right, I should shoot the Ray from the ball and tilt a little bit to hit the side of the mesh collider of the plane and calculate the distance of the hit and when it became a reasonable small value then change the direction of the movement, is that the idea?

Comment: @armnotstrong the idea is just need to shoot the ray in every side of the ball the left - right - up - down and calculate the how much it distance it needs to start slowing down . Just like that .

Comment: @TheGinxx009 but since the ball is always above the plane, the ray will never hit the side part of the mesh collider

Comment: I'll post an answer if you don't mind . But i know it wouldn't be an answer. Just to show you an idea

Comment: @TheGinxx009 that will be very helpful, ideas always are more important than code :D

Answer (score 2):

The `OnCollisionExit` function is called when the object is no longer colliding with the other object. In, your case, it will be called not when the ball is on the edge of the plane but when the ball is no longer touching the plane.

The safest way to do this is to use a BoxCollider. I suggest you just use Unity's Cube primitive which comes with a BoxCollider. The mesh on it will be useful and should act as a visual guide when resizing the BoxCollider.

**1**.Go to *GameObject* ---> *3D Object* ---> *Cube* and create new Cube Objects. Looking at the shape of your plane, you will need **6** BoxColliders so this means that you need 6 cubes.

**2**.Resize, move and rotate each one until you they cover each side of the plane.

**3**.Create new layer and call it "Boundary". Select each cube and set the layer to "Boundary".

**4**.Got to *Edit* ---> *Project Settings* ---> *Physics* and use the Layer Collision Matrix to make sure that "Boundary" cannot collide with "Boundary".

**5**.Disable or remove `MeshRenderer` of each cube and that's that.

The code in your question is unnecessary but if you still want it to reflect then use `OnCollisionEnter` and check when the ball hits the wall.

Attach to the ball:

```
Rigidbody rb;
public float force = 50;

void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
    if (col.collider.CompareTag("Boundary"))
        rb.AddForce(col.contacts[0].normal * force, ForceMode.Impulse);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the advice, but the size of the plane (ie, the boundary shape of the plane) will not be decided until run-time, actually it may change during run-time. So, I can't edit the boundary in the editor, and editing it runtime with code seems a lot of work and bug oriented, I am seeking a way to avoid that. maybe  Raycast is a promisor, trying that now.

Comment: A raycast is another way to do this but the chances of the ball going off that plane is high with a raycast. *"the boundary shape of the plane) will not be decided until run-time"* It doesn't matter, you can still everything in my answer via code. Create new GameObject then attach BoxCollider to it and resize/rotate them.

Answer (score 1):

So here's just an Idea as the OP agreed to put this as an answer

```
 public Layer[] layerPriorities =
{
    Layer.Enemy,
    Layer.Walkable
};

 [SerializeField] float distanceToBackground = 100f;

public delegate void OnLayerChange(Layer newLayer); // declare new delegate type
//lets use event for the protection of the layerchanges
public event OnLayerChange onlayerChange; // instantiate a observer set

//Look for and return priority layer hit
    foreach (Layer layer in layerPriorities)
    {
        var hit = RaycastForLayer(layer);
        if (hit.HasValue)
        {
            raycastHit = hit.Value;
            if(layerHit != layer){ //if layer has changed
                layerHit = layer;
                onlayerChange(layer); //call the delegate
            }
            layerHit = layer;
            return;
        }
    }
    // otherwise return background hit
    raycastHit.distance = distanceToBackground;
    layerHit = Layer.RaycastEndStop;

}
//? is a nullable parameter
RaycastHit? RaycastForLayer(Layer layer)
{
    /*(Use a bitshift) <<*/
    int layerMask = 1 << (int)layer; // lets do masking formation
    Ray ray = viewCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

    RaycastHit hit; //used as an out parameter
    bool hasHit = Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, distanceToBackground, layerMask);
    if (hasHit)
    {
        return hit;
    }
    return null;
}
```

and create an enum for that

```
public enum Layer
{
    Walkable = 8,
    RaycastEndStop = -1 //lowest priority
}
```

As the `Layer.Enemy,` You could set it to `NotWalkable` something like well it depends you.

So the small missing part here is just calculate the distance of the ball from the edge of the plane instead of clicking it . That's what I am telling you about the `SqrMagnitude`

Comment: you shoot the Ray from the click position of the screen and in my case, I should shoot the Ray from the ball, and I shall tilt the ray a little downward to make sure the ray could hit the side part of the plane, right?

Comment: yes but instead of tilting i guess just use the `SqrMagnitude` . Hahaha or yeah its up to you .